# Can i play multiplayer Wiiu games on a gamepad and a wii remote?

Tags: controllers, wii-u, wiimote

I'm buying a wii U with a gamepad, and i have money leftover to buy a wii remote alongside it, which i was going to do, but then i read somewhere that i need TWO wii remotes to play multiplayer on the  wiiu.

Is that true? I'm mostly interested in play super smash bros, but things like mario kart and super mario bros U as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short Answer: **Kinda Yes**.

---

Longer Answer: The WiiU requires the Gamepad for all of it's games. (Even if the pad is unused, it'll still be on and displaying something.) If a game support multiplayer, it's up to the developers of the game to determine what controllers work for that game.

For *Mario Party* (for example) only works with the GamePad and Wii Remotes. *Super Smash Bros* works with the Gamepad, Pro Controller, Classic Controller, Remote, Remote with Chuck, and GameCube Controller.

For the most part, most WiiU games have options to use the Wii Remote as well. Not all games will support the remote, but most of the popular ones (Smash/Kart/Bros) will work just fine.  If you have the option though, do look into getting a Pro Controller instead. (It's the same layout like the Gamepad but without the screen.) The Pro Controller is not as compatible like the Remote, but Wii Remotes can be bought and found very easily (since they where packaged with the original Wii as well) where-as the Pro Controller isn't resold as often.

Answer (score 3):

I can personally confirm it is possible to play two player with only one Wii U Gamepad and one Wiimote for many games including Super Smash Bros Wii U.

Compatibility purely depends on what the supported controllers are for the game. (e.g. some games are Wiimote only)

Comment: @NBN-Alex Not all games require the WiiU Gamepad. It is quite possible to play a lot of games without it on at all. Settings changing requires it for keyboard input though.